# Reverse Engineering Regex in R?

Tags: r, regex

I found this Regex code (in R) that can recognize the following "class" of pattern: "LETTER-NUMBER-LETTER NUMBER-LETTER-NUMBER" in a set of strings:

```
apply(my_string, 1, function(x) gsub('(([A-Z] ?[0-9]){3})|.', '\\1', toString(x)))
```

Based on the above code, it appears that the corresponding Regex "class" for "LETTER-NUMBER-LETTER NUMBER-LETTER-NUMBER" is "(([A-Z] ?[0-9]){3})|."

This leads me to my question:

Suppose I had the following input in R:

```
input = "A1B 2C3"
```

**Is there some way I can determine what "class" of Regex is contained within this string? For example, does such a function exist?**

```
output = some_function("A1B 2C3")

> output
'(([A-Z] ?[0-9]){3})|.'
```

I found this website (https://regex-generator.olafneumann.org/?sampleText=the%20follow%20abc&flags=i&selection=11%7CMultiple%20characters) that appears to perform a similar task - but is there a way to do this in R? For example (I am not sure if this is correct) :

```
string = c("s0me strIngz123", "someString3s", "S0M3 5t1ngs")

#imaginary conversion function

regex_class = some_function(string)

# output

           string                  regex_class
1 s0me strIngz123 ^[A-Za-z0-9]+.*[a-zA-Z]+123$
2    someString3s               ^[A-Za-z0-9]+$
3     S0M3 5t1ngs  ^[A-Za-z0-9]+ [A-Za-z0-9]+$
```

**Is there some way in R to determine the general "Regex Class" for different strings?**

Thank you!

Comment: Your samples are very arbitrary though. I mean `strIngz123` might as well be `[A-Za-z0-9]+` instead of `[a-zA-Z]+123` and `someString3s` might as well be `^[A-Za-z]+3s$`. So I'm thinking you'd need to look into even more generalized character classes for these inputs.

Comment: I think you are asking if there is any function which gives the regex when some input is given. Am I right?

Comment: Your function would either have to return a huge list of possible patterns or have some criteria for determining the best pattern. The obvious one would be the most computationally efficient pattern, except that in all cases the result would be the input string itself. Obviously you don't want that so I think you need a more explicit definition of what a regex class is and how to rank them.

Comment: This would only be feasible if you give a list of regexes as input to the function, then the function could determine which ones match particular input.  As @SamR said, there are too many possible matches unless you limit them.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your replies! This is all very interesting to learn about!

Comment: “Based on the above code, it appears that the corresponding Regex "class" for "LETTER-NUMBER-LETTER NUMBER-LETTER-NUMBER" is "(([A-Z] ?[0-9]){3})|."” — No, sorry, that is completely incorrect. At any rate, what you are asking is fundamentally impossible, and this can be shown trivially, because the expressions you are showing are completely arbitrarily chosen, and there are (infinitely many!) different expressions that would match the same input.

Comment: The relation between strings and regex are many-to-many, as others already pointed out. So, no, you can not build a function to do it, since a function requires a many-to-one or one-to-one relation: the output is unique given the input. Here, there are many regex that might match a given string.

Comment: @nicola It is ever possible to build a regex that will accept only one string. It will be like `paste0("\\A", string, "\\z")`. I wrote about such regexes in 1st statement of conclusion. But there are no non-zero-length strings that match a single regex only.

Comment: finding a general optimal regexp (other than string1|string2|....) is NP Hard, as [this post](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1854/is-finding-the-minimum-regular-expression-an-np-complete-problem) explains. So is unfeasible for large examples.

Comment: @ Ric: just a question  - if it is NP-Hard, then how does this website do it? https://regex-generator.olafneumann.org/?sampleText=the%20follow%20abc&flags=i&selection=11%7CMultiple%20characters thanks!

Comment: @RicVillalba The problem is specifying the term "optimal". And this is what I was trying to say in my answer. It is ever possible to manually set limitations of conversion of certain chars to this or that pattern. For instance assuming the string array to be input we can set pattern for nth char `[:lower:]` in case if there are only letters at nth position of each string of the array. You can invent the list of such rules that will help you to construct such expressions. It does not mean such patterns are optimal or there are no better patterns. So wil any training set for AI be optimal?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible to make a generalized pattern and I'll try to explain why.

As soon as there are almost no scalars in R I'll use terms for data types from Pascal:

- char (character) - a single character symbol (letter, digit or special) In R it will be for instance the result of `intToUtf8(strtoi("0x000A"))`.
- string - an array of char (characters) - no exact match in R. In terms of our discussion we can take `"ABC"` or `"ABC"[1]`.
- array of string (`character` in R). For instance `c("ABC", "DEF")`.

We can build our explanation either from the level of a char (character) towards array of string or vice versa.

*First.* The generalized algorithm is impossible for char (character). The reason is simple. Say we have a char `A`. The generalized pattern can be

- `A` only,
- `A` or `a`,
- `A` or `B` or other limited vector of permitted characters (for instance from my previous sample: letters used in hex spelling `"A":"F"` with or without `"a":"f"`),
- (uppercase) letters,
- (all) letters and digits,
- any char (letters, digits, space, punctuation marks and special).

You see that a single character does not give any sufficient information to predict the generalized pattern of `regex`.

*Second.* The generalized algorithm is impossible for a single string.

- It is not possible to automatically predict permitted position of a certain character within the string.
- There is no cybernetic reason to decide that the length of the string must be the same as the length of the sample string as well as to know the range of allowed lengths.
- It is not also possible to find out limitations of char groups that must be present (absent) inside the string.
- It is also impossible to exclude that `NA` or `""` are allowed values for such a strings upon having analysed a single `!is.na()` string. The opposite conclusion is also lawful. Having a single string `== ""` for instance we can not state that all strings must be empty.

So the position of characters, the length of the string and group of chars can not be uniquely limited upon the analysis of the single sample string.

*Third.* The array of strings is also not sufficient to build `regex`.

- At least it can be never estimated must this array have at least one member or can be `null` / 0 length.
- How many members must it have and in general is there (any) law for allowed number of such memebers.

Actually limitations for array of string have much in common with those for string.

**Conclusion.**

Upon these considerations we can make the following conclusions.

1. At least the single pattern is ever possible. This pattern will equal to analysed string.
2. The patterns for a specific char / string / array of string are not unique, and it is ever possible to build `n` `regex`'es depending upon the specific qualities of the analysed string. `n` is infinite (as soon as we assume that strings of infinite length  are allowed) or at least (very) large.
3. Adding machine learning and other AI algorithms we can reduce `n` and build more suitable `regex`'es. But all the results of AI are statistically limited and can have higher or lower significance that never reaches `1`. So these methods will give us `m` `regex`es. Though `m <= n` still `m != 1`. Even consideration that `m < n` is doubtfull as some `regex`es form `m` will be less likely but still possible.